# Azure Firewall - how to set a rule to allow Gmail SMTP 587?

Tags: azure, firewall

I have a secured environment and I use Azure Firewall. But how do I set up a rule for `smtp.gmail.com:587`? FQDN can't be used for Network rules. Application rules are not applicable?

Is there the way?

PS. I know I could use IP but what if it changes later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing Azure Firewall does not support this.

And it is a big pity :(